# Excel 2010 find matching usernames & copy emails to sheet 1 for corresponding users

Tags: excel-2010

I want to check usernames in first sheet against all of the usernames in the other sheet. And for those which are the same, copy the emails (which I have only in sheet2)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

sheet2 has a column of names
immediately to the right are the corresponding e-addresses
this data has been given a named range of LRange
your data in first sheet is a column starting in A1

then in first sheet first row and copied down to suit a formula of this kind may be what you require:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,book5!lRange,2,0),"")
```